# import bcrypt fails on anaconda cmd and throws an error "cannot import _bcrpyt" but works on windows cmd?

Tags: python, bcrypt

I have successfully installed flask_bcrypt package using anaconda pip. But I am having a weird problem when I try to import it .Using windows cmd it works well but it fails when I try to do it through anaconda prompt command, jupyter or Spyder ? I tried to restart them and run the command but still having the same problem.Using either jupyter notebook it throws an import error 'cannot import name '_bcrypt'

### bcrypt is required to use Flask-Bcrypt

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_bcrypt.py in ()
     25 except ImportError as e:
     26     print('bcrypt is required to use Flask-Bcrypt')
---> 27     raise e
     28 
     29 from sys import version_info

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_bcrypt.py in ()
     22 
     23 try:
---> 24     import bcrypt
     25 except ImportError as e:
     26     print('bcrypt is required to use Flask-Bcrypt')

C:\python\Lib\site-packages\bcrypt__init__.py in ()
     23 import six
     24 
---> 25 from . import _bcrypt
     26 from .**about** import (
     27     **author**, **copyright**, **email**, **license**, **summary**, **title**,

ImportError: cannot import name '_bcrypt'

Comment: I _guess_ it is the VirtualEnv that hurts. But you leave nearly nothing useful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed `bcrypt`? Note `flask-bcrypt`!= `bcrypt`.